# Is there expandable list widget with dragging capability in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to implement an expandable list along with sorting in Flutter.

All items in the list should be draggable - sections and child items. Child items should be movable between sections. Good video example is here: https://youtu.be/S7cSwMArjUQ?t=28

If there is no such widget yet, how could I implement this using existing widgets?

Comment: Well, [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_reorderable_list) might be a good starting point.

Comment: There is no such widget. If there are only a few items, you could use the built in reorderable list combined with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51736663/in-flutter-how-can-i-change-some-widget-and-see-it-animate-to-its-new-size